# How many blood types are there?

Tags: human-biology

In total how many blood types are there?

And why do people normally know only 8 of them? (A+, B+ , AB+ and O+ and Rh- counterparts)

Comment: As I remember from my physiology studies that there are more systems. So you're interested in the ABO system only or the other ones as well? check this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_blood_group_systems#Blood_group_systems

Comment: @zeller Thank you, anyway I cannot understand why normally we know only ABO system and I cannot understand if each system is only a different "convention" of if it denotes a somewhat different blood system.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't answer that, as I haven't studied immunology, but based on my recent readings (on wikipedia...), most of them check different antigenes/ligands/whatevers.

Comment: Adding insults to the question will not help to reopen it. Working on the content will. Comments should be added into the comment field.

Comment: @Chris insults? What's not clear in "This question has been asked before and already has an answer."? I repeat: the time line goes from left to right, from lower numbers to higher numbers. It's pretty easy.

Comment: @HAL9000 The question is not whether ur query was answered first or not.. In general it has been answered. Shouldn't you just be glad that you have been pointed to the answer. Just ask a new question for any further clarifications